# Flutter Reactive BLE - How Do I Utilize Existing BLE Connection and the Existing Event Listener on Page Change?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, listener, uart

I am writing an app in Flutter that uses flutter_reactive_ble 5.0.2. The app allows the user to connect to a BLE device via their phone. Once connected, the app sends a sequences of commands to the device that allows the device to connect to a WiFi network. Everything is working great in my initial main.dart page, but I'd like to send the user to a new page where I can generate a list view of available WiFi networks to pick from. How do I use the existing BLE connection and its associated 'event listener' in the new page?

My BLE connection is currently managed by the following code:

```
void onConnectDevice(index) async {
    deviceIndex = index;
    await scanStream.cancel();
    currentConnectionStream = flutterReactiveBle.connectToAdvertisingDevice(
      id: foundBleUARTDevices[index].id,
      withServices: [_UART_UUID, _UART_RX, _UART_TX],
      prescanDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 90),
    );
    statusUpdates = '';
    refreshScreen();
    connection = currentConnectionStream.listen((event) {
      var id = event.deviceId.toString();
      switch (event.connectionState) {
        case DeviceConnectionState.connecting:
          {
            statusUpdates = "${statusUpdates}Connecting to $id\n";
            break;
          }
        case DeviceConnectionState.connected:
          {
            connected = true;
            statusUpdates = "${statusUpdates}Connected to $id\n";
            numberOfMessagesReceived = 0;
            receivedData = [];
            txCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
              serviceId: _UART_UUID,
              characteristicId: _UART_TX,
              deviceId: event.deviceId,
            );
            receivedDataStream =
                flutterReactiveBle.subscribeToCharacteristic(txCharacteristic);
            receivedDataStream.listen((data) {
              onNewReceivedData(data);
            }, onError: (dynamic error) {
              statusUpdates = "${statusUpdates}Error:$error$id\n";
            });
            rxCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
              serviceId: _UART_UUID,
              characteristicId: _UART_RX,
              deviceId: event.deviceId,
            );
            bleConnectionMessage = 'BLE connected';
            break;
          }
        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnecting:
          {
            connected = false;
            statusUpdates = "${statusUpdates}Disconnecting from $id\n";
            break;
          }
        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
          {
            statusUpdates = "${statusUpdates}Disconnected from $id\n";
            break;
          }
      }
      refreshScreen();
    });
  }
```

`onNewReceivedData` is listening to messages (command responses) coming over the UART.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?